# BIOS Logo doesn't appear after update

Tags: bios

I have problem with my bios. recently I've updated my bios and It was successfully updated and it's automatically restart the computer. but, when the computer start again the bios logo it doesn't appear, i.e. it's just a black screen and it's not continue to the operating system. but i figured it out the way to use my computer again is to reset the bios each time i want to use it. i've tried to pull out the **CMOS** and it doesn't working, also i try to downgrade the bios but, it's said: "You trying to downgrade the bios Access Denied". is there is a way to fix my computer back to normal?

**Motherboard:** Dell Inspiron 530

Comment: [Edit] the question to add information. Comments are not for this.

Comment: @Alvin_Sanchez add more info {manufacturer's site and product info page pc/motherboard} like Kamil Maciorowski said